# How to optimize the javascript code snippet?

Tags: javascript, html

May I know how to optimize the below code snippet? That mean make the code simple or better readability.

```
if (x == 0) {
  y = y + 2;
  console.log(y);
} else {
  y = y + 3;
  console.log(y);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "optimize"?

Comment: Make it simple code.

Comment: `y += 2; if (x) y++; console.log(y);` Or: `console.log(y + (x ? 3 : 2));` (not sure if that's simple though)

Comment: Simple meaning reduced lines or better readability?

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt Yes

Comment: I had an `or` in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for this and add 2 or 3 to y based on condition if `x == 0`

```js
let y = 1, x = 0;
y += x == 0 ? 2 : 3;
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code like so:

```
y += 2 + (x ? 0 : 1);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line. If x is 0 then add 2 to `y` or add `3`

```
y = 0 === x ? y + 2 : y + 3;
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be modified as:

```
y = !x ? y+2 : y+3
console.log(y);
```